# Batch or .exe via SSIS package fails to give output despite of success status of SQL Agent Job

Tags: batch-file, ssis, exe, sql-server-2008

I have created a batch file which starts a command line (IrfanView) with several arguments. The batch looks like this:

```
start /wait /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView" i_view32.exe C:\Source\*.png /advancedbatch /convert=C:\Destination\*.jpg
```

Basically it converts all PNG from source folder to JPEG using advanced batch settings stored in INI of IrfanView to destination folder.

The batch file is located on my server (same as IrfanView) and when manually started it works fine. I also tried to start the batch using SSIS execute process task, which also works when package executes manually.

Another option was to start IrfanView directly from the execute process task (so no batch file) and then manually trigger the package. Every option seems to work manually.

However, whenever I try to run the batch (cmdExec) or any package in SQL Agent it will run the job successfully, but... there is no output in the folder. So, it doesn't give an error, it simple does nothing.

When run manually the output files will appear as expected in the destination folder.
When run through SQL Agent no output files will appear although the job was run successfully.

Could it have to do with security settings? SQL Agent runs under local user with full administrator rights.
I have read something about credentials and proxy, but not sure how to use it and if it will solve the problem.

I have another job running which also calls an executable (7zip) in a SSIS package and it works fine.

If I use another program, for example Flash Renamer from command line, then the SQL Job keeps running (status in progress), while triggering the package or batch manually it works fine.

Using SQL Server 2008 (BIDS + SSMS)

How can this be resolved?

Comment: It smells like permissions since it works for your account but not the SQL Agent account. For the job that runs 7zip, does it use Stored Credentials? If it's not, then if you modify your batch script to convert 1 file in that exists in the same folder that 7zip operates in, and emits it to the same location -  does that work? I expect it will which means the account running your package needs file system access to `C:\Source` and/or `C:\Destination`

Comment: Do you have a solution for this problem? I'm on the same. Tried multiple options, using cmd or even powershell but nothing works.
It works if I run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Command [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx) often interprets first double quoted string as title string. Therefore it is necessary to specify a title in double quotes if any other string must be enclosed also in double quotes.

*IrfanView* does not require that its program directory is the current working directory. Therefore simply starting *IrfanView* with full path would be better in my point of view.

*IrfanView* option *advancedbatch* requires data from `i_view32.ini`. On running *IrfanView* with a different account, it will be necessary most likely to specify the path to the folder containing `i_view32.ini`.

`i_view32.ini` is usually stored either in program files directory of *IrfanView* or in directory "**%APPDATA%\IrfanView**".

The first option is usually not used anymore as default program files location "**%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView**" on Windows x64 or "**%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView**" on Windows x86 is write-protected by default for users of Windows Vista and later Windows versions.

Therefore `i_view32.ini` is nowadays by default in application data directory of *IrfanView* of **current user account**.

Yes, environment variable **APPDATA** contains name of the user account and differs therefore from user account to user account. And by default user X has no permission to access the application data directory of user Y.

So on running *IrfanView* with a different account, file `i_view32.ini` or a copy of it containing the advanced batch conversion options must be located in a folder readable for all user accounts or at least the used account and on command line the path to this folder must be specified, too.

With summarizing up all information above, you would need most likely

```
start "Convert PNG to JPEG" /wait "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" C:\Source\*.png /advancedbatch /convert=C:\Destination\*.jpg /ini="Path to folder with i_view32.ini" /cmdexit
```

But below should also work if the batch file does not contain any other commands and therefore no batch file is needed at all.

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" C:\Source\*.png /advancedbatch /convert=C:\Destination\*.jpg /ini="Path to folder with i_view32.ini" /cmdexit
```